# How to create Picture and HTML formats all together on the clipboard?

Tags: delphi, clipboard, delphi-xe4

I need to create the following formats all together on the clipboard:

**CF_BITMAP

CF_DIB

CF_DIB5

HTML Format**

This is a console program which can create either the picture formats OR the HTML Format, but not all together on the clipboard:

```
program CopyImageFromFile;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}
{$R *.res}

uses
  Winapi.Windows,
  Vcl.Clipbrd,
  Vcl.ExtCtrls,
  Vcl.Imaging.pngimage,
  System.SysUtils;

function FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(HTMLText: string): string;
const
  CrLf = #13#10;
begin
  Result := 'Version:0.9' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndHTML:-1' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'StartFragment:000081' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + 'EndFragment:°°°°°°' + CrLf;
  Result := Result + HTMLText + CrLf;
  Result := StringReplace(Result, '°°°°°°', Format('%.6d', [Length(Result)]), []);
end;

procedure CopyHTMLAndImageToClipBoard(const str, APngFile: AnsiString; const htmlStr: AnsiString = '');
var
  gMem: HGLOBAL;
  lp: PChar;
  Strings: array[0..1] of AnsiString;
  Formats: array[0..1] of UINT;
  i: Integer;

  ThisImage: TImage;
  MyFormat: Word;
  Bitmap: TBitMap;
  AData: THandle;
  APalette: HPALETTE;
begin
  gMem := 0;
  //{$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
  //Win32Check(OpenClipBoard(0));
  //{$ENDIF}
  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    //most descriptive first as per api docs
    Strings[0] := FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr);
    Strings[1] := str;
    Formats[0] := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
    Formats[1] := CF_TEXT;
    {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    Win32Check(EmptyClipBoard);
    {$ENDIF}
    for i := 0 to High(Strings) do
    begin
      if Strings[i] = '' then Continue;
      //an extra "1" for the null terminator
      gMem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, Length(Strings[i]) + 1);
      {Succeeded, now read the stream contents into the memory the pointer points at}
      try
        Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
        lp := GlobalLock(gMem);
        Win32Check(lp <> nil);
        CopyMemory(lp, PChar(Strings[i]), Length(Strings[i]) + 1);
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(gMem);
      end;
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      SetClipboardData(Formats[i], gMEm);
      Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
      gmem := 0;
    end;

    ThisImage := TImage.Create(nil);
    try
      ThisImage.Picture.LoadFromFile(APngFile);
      // Comment this out to copy only the HTML Format:
      Clipboard.Assign(ThisImage.Picture);
      {MyFormat := CF_PICTURE;
      ThisImage.Picture.SaveToClipBoardFormat(MyFormat, AData, APalette);
      ClipBoard.SetAsHandle(MyFormat, AData);}
    finally
      ThisImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    //{$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    //Win32Check(CloseClipBoard);
    //{$ENDIF}
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;

var
  HTML: string;

begin
  try
    // Usage: CopyImageFromFile.exe test.png
    // test.png is 32 bit with alpha channel
    if ParamCount = 1 then
    begin
      if FileExists(ParamStr(1)) then
      begin
        if LowerCase(ExtractFileExt(ParamStr(1))) = '.png' then
        begin
          HTML := '<img border="0" src="file:///' + ParamStr(1) + '">';
          CopyHTMLAndImageToClipBoard('test', ParamStr(1), HTML);
        end;
      end;
    end;
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
      Readln;
    end;
  end;

end.
```

So how can I create all these formats together on the clipboard?

Comment: Call SetClipboardData once for each format.

Comment: How would you do all the global memory stuff for ThisImage.Picture?

Comment: Well, I would not mix all the code into one big glob like this. I'd separate it out into functions with specific and distinct tasks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TClipboard` empties the clipboard the first time you use a `TClipboard` method to put data on the clipboard (`TClipboard.Assign()`, `TClipboard.SetBuffer()`, `TClipboard.SetAsHandle()`, etc) after calling `Open()`.  `TClipboard` expects you to use only its methods for accessing the clipboard, so your use of `SetClpboardData()` directly to store your string data is bypassing `TClipboard`'s internal logic, thus your call to `Assign()` is seen as the first clipboard write and `TClipboard` wipes out any data you stored with `SetClipboardData()`.

To avoid that, you have a few choices:

1. `Assign()` your image to the clipboard first, then save your string items with `SetClipboardData()` afterwards.
2. don't use `Assign()` at all.  Use `TPicture.SaveToClipboardFormat()` directly and then call `SetClipboardData()`.
3. don't use `SetClipboardData()` directly unless `USEVCLCLIPBOARD` is not defined.  Use `TClipboard.SetAsHandle()` instead.

I would suggest #3.  Let `TClipboard` do all of the work:

```
var
  CF_HTML: UINT = 0;

// TClipboard.SetBuffer() allows a format and an arbitrary buffer
// to be specified and handles the global memory allocation.
// However, it is protected, so using an accessor class to reach it.
//
// TClipboard.AsText and TClipboard.SetTextBuf() always use
// CF_(UNICODE)TEXT, and TClipboard.SetAsHandle() requires manual
// allocation...
//
type
  TClipboardAccess = class(TClipboard)
  end;

procedure CopyHTMLAndImageToClipBoard(const str, APngFile: AnsiString; const htmlStr: AnsiString = '');
var
  TmpHtmlStr: AnsiString;
  ThisImage: TPicture;
begin
  Clipboard.Open;
  try
    //most descriptive first as per api docs

    TmpHtmlStr := FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr);
    TClipboardAccess(Clipboard).SetBuffer(CF_HTML, PAnsiChar(TmpHtmlStr)^, Length(TmpHtmlStr) + 1);
    TClipboardAccess(Clipboard).SetBuffer(CF_TEXT, PAnsiChar(Str)^, Length(Str) + 1);

    ThisImage := TPicture.Create;
    try
      ThisImage.LoadFromFile(APngFile);
      Clipboard.Assign(ThisImage);
    finally
      ThisImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    Clipboard.Close;
  end;
end;

initialization
  CF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
```

If you really need to support `{$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}` then you cannot use `TClipboard` at all, eg:

```
var
  CF_HTML: UINT = 0;

{$IFDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
// TClipboard.SetBuffer() allows a format and an arbitrary buffer
// to be specified and handles the global memory allocation.
// However, it is protected, so using an accessor class to reach it.
//
// TClipboard.AsText and TClipboard.SetTextBuf() always use
// CF_(UNICODE)TEXT, and TClipboard.SetAsHandle() requires manual
// allocation...
//
type
  TClipboardAccess = class(TClipboard)
  end;
{$ENDIF}

procedure CopyHTMLAndImageToClipBoard(const str, APngFile: AnsiString; const htmlStr: AnsiString = '');
var
  ThisImage: TPicture;
  {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
  ImgData: THandle;
  ImgFormat: Word;
  ImgPalette: HPALETTE;
  {$ENDIF}

  procedure SetAsText(Format: UINT; const S: AnsiString);
  {$IFNDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
  var
    gMem: HGLOBAL;
    lp: PAnsiChar;
  {$ENDIF}
  begin
    {$IFDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    TClipboardAccess(Clipboard).SetBuffer(Format, PAnsiChar(S)^, Length(S) + 1);
    {$ELSE}
    //an extra "1" for the null terminator
    gMem := GlobalAlloc(GMEM_DDESHARE + GMEM_MOVEABLE, Length(S) + 1);
    Win32Check(gmem <> 0);
    try
      {Succeeded, now read the stream contents into the memory the pointer points at}
      lp := GlobalLock(gMem);
      Win32Check(lp <> nil);
      try
        CopyMemory(lp, PAnsiChar(S), Length(S) + 1);
      finally
        GlobalUnlock(gMem);
      end;
    except
      GlobalFree(gMem);
      raise;
    end;
    SetClipboardData(Format, gMem);
    {$ENDIF}
  end;

begin
  {$IFDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
  Clipboard.Open;
  {$ELSE}
  Win32Check(OpenClipBoard(0));
  {$ENDIF}
  try
    //most descriptive first as per api docs
    SetAsText(CF_HTML, FormatHTMLClipboardHeader(htmlStr));
    SetAsText(CF_TEXT, Str);

    ThisImage := TPicture.Create;
    try
      ThisImage.LoadFromFile(APngFile);

      {$IFDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
      Clipboard.Assign(ThisImage);
      {$ELSE}
      ImgPalette := 0;
      ThisImage.SaveToClipboardFormat(ImgFormat, ImgData, ImgPalette);
      SetClipboardData(ImgFormat, ImgData);
      if ImgPalette <> 0 then
        SetClipboardData(CF_PALETTE, ImgPalette);
      {$ENDIF}
    finally
      ThisImage.Free;
    end;
  finally
    {$IFDEF USEVCLCLIPBOARD}
    Clipboard.Close;
    {$ELSE}
    Win32Check(CloseClipBoard);
    {$ENDIF}
  end;
end;

initialization
  CF_HTML := RegisterClipboardFormat('HTML Format');
```

Comment: I did not find "Clipboard.SetAsBuffer" anywhere. Where is it declared?

Comment: Sorry, I did not notice that it is `protected`. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: Thanks, this is really AWESOME! I've learned a lot from you! I hope that someday I will be able to help other people in the same way you helped me!

Comment: This is strange: While the **HTML Format** can be pasted without problems in MS Word, it cannot be pasted in OpenOffice Writer. Why?

Comment: According to [this bug report](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=113171#c4), OpenOffice Writer does not format HTML correctly when storing `CF_HTML` data on the Windows clipboard, so maybe it has a related problem when loading `CF_HTML` data from the clipboard? Who knows. There is a [known bug](https://issues.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=113171) with OpenOffice Writer not pasting clipboard text correctly in general, which may also be playing into it.  As long as MSWord is working correctly, then your code is working correctly, the problem is on OpenOffice's end.

Comment: I have added the CF_HDROP format, so the image now can also be pasted in OpenOffice Writer without problems and in other programs which can paste CF_HDROP image files. Next I'll support other image file types too.

Answer (score 2):

David is right. You need to have one pair of open/close, and only one EmptyClipboard.  You need to iterate through your formats and call SetClipboardData for each one.
RegisterClipboardFormat should only be called once, so do that in some initialization routine.
I would also try to avoid doing any file I/O once you've opened the clipboard, as you don't want to hold it open longer than necessary.  i.e. read your pictures from disk first, if possible.